# Круче или кручи?

Tags: существительные, склонение

Как правильно в дательном падеже пишется слово кручь? Кручи или круче?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке есть слово КРУЧА. Это существительное 1-го склонения, поэтому в дательном падеже оно имеет форму КРУЧЕ.

Вы правы, Серж: в словаре Ефремовой есть слово КРУЧЬ с  пометой "местн.". В этом случае, конечно, в дательном падеже диалектное слово КРУЧЬ будет иметь окончание -И (кручи).

Answer (score 2):

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/круть

не все так просто, есть подводные камни, которые обходят различными производными.

Answer (score 0):

Екатерина, в словаре синонимов на Грамоте.ру слово кручь присутствует. Однако ни в одном другом словаре мне не удалось найти это слово.

Answer (score 0):

Если с пометой "местн.", тогда это ж.р., 3 скл. Следовательно, (чему?) мыши, печи, кручи. Хотя звучит странно.